# LeakCanary: No errors in debug modus

Tags: debugging, memory-leaks, leakcanary

The Memory Leaks occur only in release modus (normal start) and there are no LC errors by debugging. Is it how LC should work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Leakcanary will do nothing when a debugger is attached. The reason is that the debugger may create false positives.

Note that this is slightly different from "debug mode". You can compile an application for debug mode but still run it normally (without a debugger attached).

Comment: @StefanOS: you're welcome. If you can somehow confirm that, please check the checkmark to mark this issue as solved. If you found the answer helpful, please click the up arrow button.

Comment: It must be possible to check the checkmark for any reputation